# Diferencia en significado usando modales

Tags: verbos

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las expresiones

- Ella pudo verme.
- Ella pudo haberme visto
  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La frase *ella pudo verme* puede tener dos significados distintos:

- Existía la posibilidad de que me hubiera visto, pero no sé si lo hizo.
- Ella fue capaz de verme.

Sin embargo, la frase *ella pudo haberme visto* significa:

- Existía la posibilidad de que me hubiera visto, pero no lo llegó a hacer.